# Rails image url in poduction

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image, asset-pipeline, production

When I put my website in production using `git push heroku master` the url in my CSS does not refer to the right image url.

Here is my situation in development environment :

- app/assets/images/logo.png is present
- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb : `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style" %>`
- app/assets/stylesheets/style.css : `background: asset-url("logo.png");`

Here is my situation in production (when I "View Page source") :

- I don't know how to find logo.png ?
- Link to my CSS : `<link href="/assets/style-75a5c3912777c4b39ba92d1893ac7815.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />`
- In my (compressed) CSS I can find : `background:asset-url("logo.png");`

For the others images called directly from app/views/* it's ok (`<%= link_to image_tag("xxx.png") %>`)

In config/environments/production.rb I have :

```
config.assets.precompile += ['style.css']
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

I'm following [this great tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/).

Comment: so what does URL does it refer to in production? because if your compiled CSS still says `asset-url('logo.png')`, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: CSS still says asset-url('logo.png') .... :/

Comment: @ZazOufUmI How are you making url for your image? are you sure logo.png is present in app/assets/images and not app/assets/images/some_folder because. if it's in images folder then asset-url or image-url will make proper paths for you

Comment: are you compiling the CSS file from sass/scss? They provide the `asset-url` helper methods for you.

Comment: I updated my request. Yes @sevenseacat I used those commands once to help me resolved another issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695809/heroku-css-not-loading-after-assetsprecompile/19696598#19696598

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid css on rails app Michael Hartl tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839662/invalid-css-on-rails-app-michael-hartl-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem thanks to multiple answers found here and somewhere else (can't found where anymore sorry). Here is my solution to make things work without putting all my ressources into the public folder.

1. I deleted all ressources from public/images & stylesheets & javascript
2. I renamed my style.css to style.css.scss.erb
3. I replace every `background: url("../images/xxx.png");` to `background: url(<%=asset_path "xxx.png"%>);` from my CSS
4. I executed this command before pushing into production : `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Thanks @RichPeck for your post which helps me to understand the process of assets pipelines

Answer (score 3):

**SCSS**

The problem, from what I can see, is that you're not using any [CSS preprocessors (SCSS / SASS)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing), cancelling out the ability for the Rails helper `asset-url`.

I'd do this to start with:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/style.css.scss
background: asset-url("logo.png");
```

---

**Asset Pipeline**

This will make sense if you look at how the [`asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark) works

Basically, the asset pipeline is a place to put all your `css` / `image` / `javascript` files, which your application can call, either statically or dynamically. Whilst in development, the `asset_pipeline` works very well to provide you with a central location for all your files -- all being called dynamically.

--

**Production**

The "problems" happen when most people want to use the asset pipeline [in production](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production). Production generally requires *static* assets, which means [*precompilation*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets):

> In the production environment Sprockets uses the fingerprinting scheme
>   outlined above. By default Rails assumes assets have been precompiled
>   and will be served as static assets by your web server.

Asset precompilation is when Rails will "compile" your CSS / Image / Javascript files into a series of ["minified" versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) - making them much more efficient to load

The problem with the precompilation process is actually loses all the "dynamic" aspects of the files, meaning if you want to include things like `asset-url`, you'll need to use a `preprocessor` to manage the dynamic aspects of these files.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I precompiled my code using bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production but the problem is always here. I don't get how to bypass this :/

Comment: you're not using sass, which provides the helpers.